# Javascript/HTML: How to dynamically add various input types and receive them on server side?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

**Pardon me if the question is long, but as a programmer (who isn't much familiar with JavaScript and HTML), I know it is an easy one for you professionals. Besides, I've kept the question detailed with photos of actual webpage.**

I'm making a webpage in html/javascript (to be used as a template with a python/flask/jinja app). In it, the scenarios are as follows:

**Scenario A**

*The user opens a webpage to upload a file.* The page shows something like:
[image]

When the user clicks on "Add another file", more file upload inputs are added like:
[image]

The code used to do so is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counterFile = 1;
    function addFile(){
        var item1 = document.getElementById("UploadedFile1");
        var cloned = item1.cloneNode(true);
        counterFile = counterFile + 1;
        cloned.setAttribute("id", "UploadedFile" + counterFile);
        var sectiondiv = document.getElementById("UploadFileSection");
        sectiondiv.appendChild(cloned);
        linebreak = document.createElement("br");
        sectiondiv.appendChild(linebreak);
    }
</script>
```

Now how do I receive the files on the other side? Can I make an array so that I don't have to receive the files individually? And how to set a counter for the same?

**Scenario B**

The files uploaded in the previous section are stored and a reference number given to user for later use. Then, the user can do manipulation on this data of the uploaded file(s).

Now the user is presented with an option a manipulation of his choice through a list box like:
[image]

[image]

The code used to dynamically add another filter is same as previous one. Now suppose the user selects Option 1 (and there will be 15-16 such options). Now new inputs next to the Option List are to be added to take user inputs on how to manipulate data based on that option 1(for example, option 1 can enable user to show only data between specific dates). In Option 2, user may want to show data containing specific words. So, the number of new inputs to be added when user selects an option will vary with the kind of option selected.

**How to add these new inputs dynamically? And again, how to receive them on the server side?**

Comment: There's actually like 10 questions embedded in this post, I suggest you break it down to something more manageable.

Comment: For the first one though, you might want to look at this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/fileuploads/